# Is "My teeth chatter" a form of personification?

Tags: phrases, literary-device, personification

Is the phrase "my teeth chatter" (due to the cold) an example of personification? Teeth can't literally chatter, but they *can* make a chattering noise, so I am a bit torn on this one.

Comment: "Chatter" is a sound.  A machine may make a "chatter" sound, as may teeth.  And groups of women often make a chattering sound.

Comment: Your teeth are making a rattling noise, they are not 'talking informally'.